# dompdf not getting css on partial view

Tags: php, laravel, dompdf

When I try to expord a pdf file using dompdf, it shows a plain text with no format. In the view, it takes perfectly the css classes from bootstrap but when it generates the pdf, its just plain text.

the only way it works, is applying styles directly to that partial view using an `<style></style>` tag.

`<div class="panel-body">
    @if (isset($user)) 
        @include('_pdf')
        <a href="{{ route('register.export', $user) }}" class="btn btn-danger pull-right" target="_blank">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-save-file"></span> Export 
    </a>
    @endif
</div>`

it wont make any of bootstrap css

Comment: Are you using this barryvdh/laravel-dompdf ? This has known issues with bootstrap. I usually use barryvdh/laravel-snappy if a lot of css is involved

Comment: @indra, and with this, it reflects the css in the PDF generated from the partial view?

Comment: I mean, I dont want to have to customize the css inside a `<stlye>` tag on that patial view. I want to take the styling from the view I am @including this one (that is @yielded from the layout) If snappy resolve this, for sure I will use it. Thanks @indra

Comment: you should give it a try. I usually have repartee view for pdf, but don't do any css inside, i just use the main blades or pdf blades, depending on what I need. The issue is that dompdf dies when the information you feed to it it's too large. That's why it's not working your css in the file